# Structuring a Work Schedule in an SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I'm in the process of building an ASP.NET site that will allow employees to view their work schedules online. When they log in, they will be able to to view their scheduled hours during the current pay period (two weeks). I would like a manager to be able to log in to the site and schedule employee hours (employees cannot change their information). I would like all the information to be stored in a database and I want the database to keep track of historical information.

How should I go about creating the tables?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit vague in my opinion, as we don't know exactly how in depth you want to go with this scheduler.  Do you plan to keep track of employee availability, company holidays, things of that nature?

This question here on SO may be similar enough to get you started, or at least point you in the right direction.

[Scheduling Employees - what data structure to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634248/scheduling-employees-what-data-structure-to-use)

This DBForums thread will probably be worth a read as well:

http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1631582-database-design-shift-scheduling.html